# Passing values ​between 2 arraylists

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Hi I have two arraylists, in the first arraySpinner are loaded with the present values ​​of a given object, I have to extrapolate the string field and add to the arraylist arrayTemp how can I do?

**Code:**

```
ArrayList<Tipologia> arraySpinner=Articolo.CaricamentoTipologie();
ArrayList<String> arrayTemp=new ArrayList<String>(); 
//Object Tipologia
public class Tipologia implements Serializable {

    private int IdTipologiaArticolo;
    private String Nome;

    public Tipologia(int IdTipologiaArticolo, String Nome) {
        this.Nome = Nome;
        this.IdTipologiaArticolo = IdTipologiaArticolo;
    }

    public String GetNomeTipologia(){
        return Nome;
    }

    public int GetIdTipologiaArticolo(){
        return IdTipologiaArticolo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read "[ask]". We're having to guess why your code doesn't work because we can't test it and don't know if there are errors being returned or what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
ArrayList<Tipologia> arraySpinner=Articolo.CaricamentoTipologie();
```

You have multiple `Tipologia` objects. You can simply iterate them:

```
for (Tipologia tipo : arraySpinner) {
  arrayTemp.add(tipo.GetNomeTipologia());
}
```

And a few hints:

- follow java naming conventions: method names go camelCase()
- prefer to use the `List` interface where possible, like `List<String> tipoNames=new ArrayList<String>();` (and use names that **say** what they are)

For the record: you could also use java streams, like:

```
List<String> names = arraySpinner.stream().map(tipo -> tipo.GetNomeTipologia()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That "streams" the elements of your arraySpinner list, and for each entry, it will call that get method, which creates a stream of Strings, which we finally push into a new List.